# XeTeX problem..Pdf output(win10)

Tags: xetex

I want to deploy XeTeX for betting OpenType Fonts and I have this problem. Thanks for the reply.[image]

Comment: You seem to have called xetex instead of xelatex. Beside this: To create a missing format (a "memory dump") go to miktex settings (admin), tab format, select the format and click on build. If you get an error: copy the log and ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have installed font Nakula. After installing font you can use your code and compile with xelatex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\dn{\catcode`\~=12
\fontspec[Script=Devanagari,%
Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit]{Nakula}}
\begin{document}
{\dn
atha ga.nitapraarambhe.abhii.s.tadevataa.m naaskaroti|
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0mm}
\item nanu pratyadhyaayamabhii.s.tadevataapra.natipratij~nota
granthaarambhe k.rtanamaskaare.naabhii.s.tasiddhirbhavati|
punari.s.tadevataanamaskaare.na ki.m saadhya.m|
\item ucyate divya.m hyatitndriya.m j~naana.m ga.nita.m
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: nakula]

Comment: I installed a font, but it's still not working. I think it's a mistake to seek fonts or something. And the present is still the same error in the compilation as img.

Comment: In my system it works perfectly.